# Lost access to Ubuntu 16.04 after restoring windows 10 to factory-settings

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, restore

I had some trouble with the windows 10 sound driver, so I decided to fully restore the system to the factory-settings as it was the easier way to solve it. 

It had two main consequences:
  - My updated Windows 10 disappeared and was restored to Windows 8.
  - Dual-boot disappeared and I lost access to Ubuntu, but partitions are still there.
I want to restore the **dual-boot** menu so I can use both Ubuntu and Windows. I've been checking a great deal of forums, but most of the suggested solutions involve risking too much for typing wrongly the partition name or do not even menction *dual-boot*, so I could gain access to Ubuntu again, but I could lose access to Windows, and both of them are important for me. Is there any way to do it in a safe and easy way?
UPDATE: I got to Ubuntu using Windows Boot Repair and I managed to install *Boot-Info* using the Terminal. It wrote the following report: http://paste2.org/d0j4ZDkJ

Comment: Was Win8 installed prior to this?

Comment: Yes, I bought the laptop with Win8.1 installed on it, but then I updated it to Windows 10, taking advantage of the free update. It was while I had Windows 10 when I installed Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I posted about using an Ubuntu live install disk to reinstall the grub bootloader and give you access to both installs again. It was downvoted, so I removed it in case I was missing something crucial. That would fix the problem as stated above. Are you looking for a different answer, or do you have additional details?

Comment: I managed to solve it! The OS selecting menu has just come back after booting the partition identified as _ubuntu_ after I clicked on Repair > Advanced Boot, in windows 8.1